# OpenGL wih Qt5: #error gl.h included before glew.h

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, glew

I have project on Qt4.8 and trying to build it with Qt5.1. I receive lots of

```
#error gl.h included before glew.h
```

and

```
#error glext.h included before glew.h
```

errors. Seems like it was big changes in Qt5 with OpenGL.. All includes are

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
```

glew.h is always the first.

Comment: Did you include something else first that includes `gl.h`? Like Qt headers, perhaps? GLEW should be included before any of them.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, #include "GL/glew.h" is always the first

Comment: precompiled headers maybe?

Comment: @dowhilefor aren't used

Comment: Check your cpps aswell, read the comments on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580675/error-gl-h-included-before-glew-h) answer, maybe that helps.

Comment: @dowhilefor files are always included that three in that order and on first line of the file. It works well with Qt4.8, so it must be something changed in Qt5..

Comment: @Littlebitter: But by your own admission, you haven't *included* anything from Qt yet, so it cannot possible affect anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas but header that includes GL are included into other files, and that files are included into others.. I think that some Qt header that didn't it now includes gl.h

Comment: @Littlebitter: When asked if you included anything before GLEW's header that might include gl.h, you "no, #include "GL/glew.h" is always the first". Did you actually mean *first*, or just first among OpenGL stuff? Because the latter is not what I asked.

Comment: @NicolBolas in files where they are included they are the first. But they are included in several headers, and that headers are included in other headers, and they in others. Project is very large.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the header is included first in some .h file. Header files are not standalone. What matters is the order that includes are seen from the source file.

You seem to have too many header inclusions (generally speaking, you should keep header-to-header inclusions to an absolute minimum). There's nothing that can be done on our end to fix that; you just need to untangle your header issues.

Comment: This is too poor to be selected as the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Suposing you only use OPENGL calls in a class where you use functions you need to load using GLEW, then this will work.

What i did to fix this is to include all GLEW h's in the .CPP file, but BEFORE the inclusion of the header file (where the QTGUI which in turn contains OPENGL).

So this is the way for me in GLWIDGET.CPP:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <GLWidget.h>
```

As you can see, my GLWidget is a derived class coming from QGLWidget, which needs to include QTGUI and all of that.